# Setting SFML 2.4.2 on CodeBlocks 16.01

Tags: gcc, mingw, codeblocks, sfml, mingw-w64

I am trying to run SFML project on CodeBlocks version 16.01.  I use `SFML 2.4.2 (GCC 4.9.2 TDM (SJLJ) - 32-bit)` from this [link](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.4.2/). My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.  I put the extracted SFML folder to `C:\SFML-2.4.2\`  On the project build options, this is the setting that I use:

```
Search Directories -> Compiler
    C:\SFML-2.4.2\include

Search Directories -> Linker
    C:\SFML-2.4.2\lib
```

For the Debug option on Linker settings tab, I put this in link libraries:

```
sfml-graphics-d
sfml-window-d
sfml-system-d
```

For the Release option on Linker settings tab, I put this in link libraries:

```
sfml-graphics
sfml-window
sfml-system
```

After that, when I try to run this code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

I got this error:

```
||=== Build: Release in NewSFML (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-graphics|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-window|
ld.exe||cannot find -lsfml-system|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Anyone know what is wrong with my setting?

Comment: I am using MingW64 GCC Compiler version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)

Comment: Did you verify the `lib` folder is exactly there and the files are directly inside it? In theory you could have extracted everything to a sub folder by accident.

Comment: yes, i've checked it and all of the libraries files are exactly inside the `lib` folder

Comment: Just had a quick look and it seems as if it expects the full file name (e.g. `sfml-graphics.dll`). Have you tried this? I've also seen examples providing the full path, but the search directories setting should work.

Comment: the library extension is `.a`, would it still work ?

Comment: You have posted the output from the **Build messages** tab. This is not
a complete build log and is not informative enough. Please replace it with the output from the **Build log** tab